# How to restart phpmyadmin on my downloaded docker image

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin

I pulled the phpmyadmin docker image from hub.docker.com.
I need to make some changes to the config.sample.inc.php.  However, I don't know how to restart phpmyadmin so my changes will be picked up.

I ran

ps -ef | grep apache

on the container and saw a bunch of

apache2 -DFOREGROUND

processes running but again, I don't know how to restart this.  Can someone tell me how to restart phpmyadmin from the docker image from hub.docker.com?

```
# ps -ef | grep apache
root         1     0  0 00:33 ?        00:00:00 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data    17     1  0 00:33 ?        00:00:00 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data    18     1  0 00:33 ?        00:00:00 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data    19     1  0 00:33 ?        00:00:00 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data    20     1  0 00:33 ?        00:00:00 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data    21     1  0 00:33 ?        00:00:00 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
root        36    22  0 00:45 pts/0    00:00:00 grep apache
root@e24b3b0f5cd5:/var/www/html#
```

Answer (score 2):

Try by removing each image and container using `docker system prune --all` (and then 'y'). By the way, you can set up volumes over the folder where there are the files that you want to update: updating files in the folder explicited in the volumes, you will have the updates in runtime

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question.  So I only have the base image for phpmyadmin pulled into my local linux server.  There's just the one container that I started off the image.  I was hoping it was as easy as running something like service restart phpmyadmin or something like that.  There's no way to do that?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I see what you're talking about now.  You wanted me to run something like this: docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql_db_server:db -p 8080:80 -v /some/local/directory/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php phpmyadmin.  I tried and unfortunately I still have this problem :(   Seems like the only way to fix this is restart phpmyadmin everytime I run into this problem.

Comment: @Classified try to create a volume and mount it https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-volumes

`docker volume create data`
`docker run --mount source=[volume_name],destination=[path_in_container] [docker_image]`